# Tablet idle issue in New Nexus 7 (2013)

Tags: nexus-7, battery-life, 4.4-kitkat

Lately my new nexus 7 table's battery has been draining incredibly fast during idle. I noticed that the "tablet idle" item in the battery life menu is the highest out of all of them (sometimes up to 34%). Any idea why this could be happening? Additionally, I know what "tablet idle" means but what technical components actually summarize to that battery level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tablet idle makes up the battery usage that isn't tied to a specific app or function. The less you actually turn the tablet on, the higher tablet idle will be.

Your battery usage stats are a percentage of a percentage. Think about this. If your tablet battery is at 50% and tablet idle is 34%, this means that 34% of 50% of your battery was used by the tablet sitting idle and just remaining powered on. So this would equate to 17% of your battery actually being used by the tablet sitting idle. Now let's change this example. Now your battery is at 90%, but tablet idle is showing 65%. This means that only 6.5% of the 10% used was used on tablet idle.

Tablet idle should never be something to worry about. If it is high, that means it wasn't actively used much and if it is low, it was used a lot. It really is just a space filler that is comprised of everything that isn't attributable to a specific app or function of the tablet (aka everything else in the battery stats list).

If it is draining a lot more than usual in idle, it isn't tablet idle doing it. It would be the usual suspects. An app or the battery itself.